# Back Button didn't show up in new Page of Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i make a new page of flutter but in my case the back button didn't show up automatically. I watch many tutorial and they always have the back button automatically when they make a new page in flutter. anybody know how to solve this problem of mine?

Comment: Can you include your second page code and how you are navigating

Comment: Please provide a sample code of your app. How are you navigating from a page to another?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Navigator.push()` instead of `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil()`

Answer (score 0):

Add some sample of your code please. Meanwhile you can do this

```
           return Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
          leading: GestureDetector(
             onPress:(){
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
         }          ,
      child: Icon(
             Icons.arrow_back,//add color of your choice
          ), 
        ),
          title: const Text(
            "Where to?",
          ),
        ),
);
```

Comment: Why are you using a GestureDetector instead of an IconButton?

Comment: It does the same thing like `IconButton()`; It all depends with how you prefer your buttons to be.